How to Calculate Excess Real Estate Taxes with two home offices?
My wife and I each have a home office in our home. I am using Turbo Tax to do our taxes, and it seems that our property taxes exceeded the $10,000 deductible limit.
We get asked the same question for each Home Office (mine and wifes)
In TT, it says if itemizing deductions, do not put anything for excess property tax. If we aren't itemizing, to put the whole amount in the Excess box.
I don't know if I am itemizing or taking standard deduction yet?
What do I do?

Before you get to Form 8829 to calculate the business use of your home, you should complete the rest of your filing and know whether you're itemizing using Schedule A or taking the standard deduction.
First, you must allocate the mortgage interest and property taxes between personal (Schedule A) and business (what will go on Form 8829). See IRS Pub 936, "Divided use of your home" and IRS Schedule A Instructions, "State and Local Real Estate Taxes".
Once that's done and you've completed the rest of your Schedule A (itemized deductions), you should know whether you'll be taking the standard deduction ($27,700 for MFJ in 2023) or itemizing.
From there, you can move on to your Form 8829 (one for each of you) and you should now be able to answer the excess property tax question accurately.
Note that you may only use the home office deduction if the space is "used regularly and exclusively for business, regularly for daycare, or for storage of inventory or product samples". Additionally, remote and hybrid W-2 employees may not take this deduction.

"Exclusively" is the requirement that most home offices fail. It doesn't have to be a full room, but you can only claim the square footage used only for the business. If you have a desk that you use only as your home office, you might be able to claim the space that desk takes up, and maybe space for a chair in front of it. If you have a bookcase or filing cabinet which has nothing but business documents, you can probably claim the space it occupies. But if this is where you read your personal email too, or if you have offseason clothes stored there, it fails the test.
